# IE11 selectionchange event activeTarget changes activeTarget when logged

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I'm trying to get the `activeTarget` of the `selectionChange` event in IE11 when using the inbuilt search to step through the matches. In Firefox and Edge the follow code will log the the element closest to where the element is. So the input "test test" would return the link element.

In IE11 the log of the whole event will contain the anchor element in the target -> activeElement but when you try to log it it will log `event.target.activeElement` the body element be logged instead.

Does anyone know what might be going on and/or how to work around this issue? Helps much appreciated.

html:

```
 <html>
   <body>
                        <div class="block display-option-100 expandedblock">

                            <div class="expand-block block__generic-body" data-expandblock>
                            
                                <div class="block__row">
                            
                                    <div tabindex="0" class="expand-block__clickable-row" role="tab" aria-controls="114428">
                            
                                        <h2 class="block__heading expand-block__heading ">H55445DEerpfsdfdfs</h2>
                                        <span class="expand-block__statuslabel" data-nojs-hidden>
                                            <span class="statuslabel__open"></span>
                                            <span class="statuslabel__close"></span>
                                        </span>
                            
                                    </div>
                            
                                    <div id="114428" class="expand-block__content" data-expandblockcontent role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                                        
                            <p><a title="Här testar vi" href="/testi/">Testitesti Rapport</a></p>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <p><a href="test">herpderp test test</a><br><a href="herp derp">test test jfdsnjdnjf <br></a><a href="fdgfdghfgfdfdg">test tastdsoin tstest</a><br><a href="gfdgfdgfdgfd">yat yat yat yta ggdsggd</a></p>
                                    </div>
                            
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function(e) {
console.log("Selection-change Log");
//e.stopPropagation();
console.log(e);
console.warn(e.target.activeElement);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on both browsers, and it works consistently.

However, the element needs to have tabindex to be defined as boundary of the activeElement, maybe that is why you saw body element.

For this it seems to be working on IE11 as well,

```
<p  width="100%"><a tabindex="0" style="width:100%; display:inline-block;" title="Här testar vi"><span>Testitesti Rapport</span></a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This didnt help me it seems though. I get it to return the correct element selecting or highlighting stuff manually. I don't however get it to work when stepping through the search results. Does that work for you? 

It's still containing the Anchorelement when logging the whole event but when trying the log only that specifik element within the event it logs the body-element.

Did you do anything else other than adding tabindex?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using document.getSelection() and then selection.anchorNode.parentNode to get the active element instead if using the event to get the relevant element.

As seen in the example here: https://chrisdavidmills.github.io/selection-api-examples/